How to Implement AWS Cognito Implicit Grant Flow in .NET Framework Web Forms Application?
I’m securing a .NET Framework Web Forms application with AWS Cognito. Initially, I used the Authorization Code flow with the Hosted UI, and it worked fine. Here’s my configuration:
public void ConfigureCodeFlowAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

   var openIdConnectConfiguration = GetConfiguration();

   var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
   {
       ClientId = clientId,
       Authority = authority,
       RedirectUri = redirectUri,
       ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
       Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
       Configuration = openIdConnectConfiguration,
       Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
       {
           SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
           {
               n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", n.ProtocolMessage.RefreshToken));
               n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
               n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;

               return Task.FromResult(0);
           }
       },
   };

   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
}

However, due to limitations with the Hosted UI, we need to create a custom login page as a separate application, which will serve multiple other applications. For this, I’m planning to use the amazon-cognito-identity-js library or AWS Amplify.
From what I understand, we need to switch our Client App to use the Implicit Grant flow (I know it’s less secure and not recommended, but it seems necessary in this case). Once I made the switch, before developing the custom login page, I wanted to test how it works with the Hosted UI, but I couldn’t get it working.
In my existing configuration, I changed the ResponseType to OpenIdConnectResponseType.Token, then OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken, and OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken. None of these seem to work correctly.
I know tokens in the Implicit Grant flow are passed as URL fragments (e.g., https://my-page.com#id_token=...). It looks like I’d need to parse these tokens manually in Page.aspx.cs, but that feels like a messy solution with a lot of manual handling. I’m hoping there’s a cleaner, more efficient way to handle this while keeping most of my previous configuration intact.
Questions:

How should I properly configure the Implicit Grant flow in my .NET
Framework Web Forms application without manually parsing tokens from
the URL fragment?
Any resources, examples, or suggestions for setting up the Implicit
Grant flow in this scenario?

I appreciate any advice or guidance you can provide. Thanks!
